# accessing a static class (or any methods) of a windows service, through the WCF service which it is hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

i have been doing a lot of research lately. i cant seem to be able to access to the windows service, which is running my wcf service. here is what i am doing.

in windows service: i collect some information from my ports and put them inside a static class. i am also hosting a wcf service.

in windows forms gui: i access to my wcf service.

its all fine. but i want my Windows Forms GUI app to be able to access the static class in my windows service through the wcf service which it can connect to via netTcpBinding. i have defined my netTcpBinding in duplex mode but i doesnt necessarily have to be this way.

I want to know if my wcf service can connect and read my static class located in my windows service. please provide codes links anything you have.

thank you

Taylan O. Sevinc

Answer (score 1):

> but i want my Windows Forms GUI app to be able to access the static
>   class in my windows service through the wcf service which it can
>   connect to via netTcpBinding

If you want this information to be accessible from the clients you will have to expose it in a service contract => write an operation contract which queries the static class and returns the data so that it is visible to the clients. Obviously since you are using a static class and you could potentially have multiple concurrent clients accessing this operation contract you will have to ensure to properly synchronize access to any shared data that you might be dealing with in this static class.

Comment: the question is really just the following: how to access a property of any sort defined in WS through WCF?

Comment: do i have an object which contains the running instance of the hosting WS in the hosted WCF?

Comment: You expose this property as a Data Contract in some of your Operation Contracts. In WCF you have service contracts: this is the interface which defines the operations that you are exposing to the clients. Those operations are called operation contracts. And the types that those operations take as arguments or return are called data contracts. So if you want some information to be accessible to the consumers of the WCF service it must be exposed in the service contract.

Comment: my friend i know the dynamics of WCF. all i want to know how i can access the host of the wcf. see my wcf is hosted in a windows service. my wcf is can also be consumed by a windows forms gui app. but i dont know the following. how does my wcf server can reach out to its server (the windows service) and say invoke a public method or fetch a public property. i know i can write that stuff in DB in windows service and have WCF connect to that DB and present it over to GUI. that would mean more traffic. i want to bypass the DB route and fetch it directly if it can be done.

Comment: In order to access a public method or property you need to reference the assembly containing this method or property in your WCF service project. I guess that your Windows Service represents a class library project that hosts the WCF service. So you might need to put the code that you want to access in another class library that you will reference in your WCF service project. This will allow you to fetch the value inside the WCF service. But if you want to pass it to the client, as I said, you will have to expose it in the service contract.